# getting undefined variable when trying to retrieve a value from a json object

Tags: jquery, json

I hesitated asking a this question in fear of getting the all feared down-vote, but after many searching and countless hours of typing, I must give in.

I'm just trying to get these values from a json object (ie `37` and `exampleoffice`):

```
{"officeId":37,"officeName":"exampleoffice"}
```

I have tried `data[0]`, `data.officeId`, `data[0][officeId]`, for loop, `$.each(data, function(i, item){})`...

I would appreciate if someone could help me and make this headache go away!

jquery:

```
$(document).on("click", "#addOffice", function() {
    var officeadd = $('#officeAddForm').serializeArray();
    console.log(officeadd);
    $.ajax({
        url:        'officeadd.php',
        type:       "POST",
        data:       officeadd,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#officecontrolgroup').append('<input type="radio" name="office" id="' + data.officeId + '" value="' + data.officeId + '"/><label for="' + data.officeId + '">' + data.officeName + '</label>').trigger('create');
            $('#officecontrolgroup').controlgroup("refresh");
            $( "#deliveryInstructions" ).trigger( "updatelayout" );
        }   
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: you need to show what is inside `data`.. Also you will need to parse `data` into a javascript object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying the dataType as json.

```
$.ajax({
  url:      'officeadd.php',
  type:         "POST",
  data:         officeadd,
  success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $('#officecontrolgroup').append('<input type="radio" name="office" id="' + data.officeId + '" value="' + data.officeId + '"/><label for="' + data.officeId + '">' + data.officeName + '</label>').trigger('create');
                $('#officecontrolgroup').controlgroup("refresh");
                $( "#deliveryInstructions" ).trigger( "updatelayout" );
           }   ,
   dataType: "json" 
});
```

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript
>   object. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON
>   is rejected and a parse error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to do:

```
data[0].officeId
```